# Word Addin - How to open a file as a new document?

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-js, office-addins

I am developing a Word add-in using Office JS in which a user can decide to open a document from a remote server API. In that case I need to receive a file from the server API and open it in Word.

Currently, I am making an HTTP request to get the document contents from the remote server encoded in Base64.

Then I am using:

```
var body = context.document.body;
body.insertFileFromBase64 (fileData, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
// (where fileData is the Base64 content)
```

This works (document is actually opened), but I don't like it so much because it replaces the current document's contents instead of opening a new document.

Is there a way to make Word open a document as a new document instead of replacing the existing document's contents?

I described my use case above in case you can also suggest a better solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot do that with javascript from the add-in. You would have to use some VBA for that

Comment: the comment by Paul is not exactly accurate, please see my answer... thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an API, in preview, you can use for this. here is a code snippet:
(note that the createDocument takes an optional parameter, a base64-encoded docx) if that's provided the opened document will include it.

in order to test the API make sure to use the preview CDN for Office.js avilable here https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js

and that you have a fresh update of Office.

here is the code:

```js
  Word.run(function (context) {
       context.application.createDocument().open();  // optionally on createDocument send a base-64 docx.
       return context.sync();
    })
```

Comment: thanks a lot for replying! I am trying that and get a "Sorry, this function isn’t available. Perform a runtime check on the Office add-in to find out whether the feature is supported by the host.". I am using Office Online. Is this only supported in the desktop version? Also, where can I find documentation on that createDocument function?

Comment: yes this is yet to be supported in Online. That's why its still preview. its supported in all the other platforms. (win32, ios, mac)